# nreco extract high quality thumbnail

Tags: c#, image

I use Nreco framwork. i call GetVideoThumbnail method, it extracts default resolution image

```
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(pathToVideoFile, "video_thumbnail.jpg");
```

How to custom option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetVideoThumbnail is a helper method that internally uses ConvertMedia to perform special conversion to the MJPEG output with only 1 frame.

You may use the following code snippet instead of calling "GetVideoThumbnail" method (and use any additional ffmpeg options you need):

```
Stream jpegOutputStream; // stream for thumbnail jpeg image output
var thumbSettings = new ConvertSettings() {
              VideoFrameRate = 1,   VideoFrameCount = 1, // extract exactly 1 frame
              Seek = 0, // frame position in seconds
              CustomOutputArgs = "" // any ffmpeg arguments that goes before output param
};
ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(pathToVideoFile, null, jpegOutputStream, "mjpeg", thumbSettings);
```