# Background playback for RTSP IP Camera in .net framework and output to http stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, video-streaming, rtsp, ip-camera

I'm currently investigating the best method to allow clients live playback IP camera where my server is the source that uses RTSP to grab the stream, so at the same time I need to be able to output that live playback to HTML5 standard player **"the video tag"** and whenever I want, I need to be able to get a snapshot pretty quickly.

I tried using **WebRequest** to fetch a snapshot but the issue is that it takes around 1 second for the camera to prepare the snapshot.

I tried another solution like in here [Extract thumbnail from RTSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950555/nreco-extract-high-quality-thumbnail) but it takes 2 seconds for that image to be ready for my application.

**Update 1**

I managed to get a single frame by using **ffmpeg.exe** via the command line interface and passing the args:

> "-i rtsp://UN:PW@IP:554/live -vframes 1 -f singlejpeg -"

And then after I start the process, I read the stream into output where it's my image binaries using:

> process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(output);

Now my only left problem is that I wanted to keep reading the rtsp and get the binaries in a rate of for example "2 frames per second". Any working code ideas?

Comment: How much data is being returned?  If you are returning a large video it will take time.

Comment: It's not much, few KBs only shouldn't take much but in either cases I'd like to continuously receive the stream as described.

Comment: So is the issue with the camera not sending data continuously?  The first snap shot I can understand having a delay.  But after the camera is started I would think there shouldn't be a delay.  Each snap shot should follow the previous.

Comment: Each will take the same time, snapshots isn't the way that's why I want to use the streaming protocol but I don't know where to start and which library to use. It's kind of rare as I couldn't fine any reliable sources.

Comment: See following codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/484731/videoplusstreamingplusinplusc-23

Comment: @jdweng thanks, I already updated my question. The link is not straight forward I prefer to keep working on my findings, just a final step is left which is iterative without closing the process.

Comment: I wished windows streams were like unix/linix.  Unix stream have one set of pointer for input and one set of pointers for output so you can simultaneously read and write at the same time.  Windows stream have only one set of pointer so you can either read or write (not both).  You are running slow.  If you were running faster I would recommend using a fifo.  It sound s like you need to block so your application doesn't close.  I like using a WaitHandle.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I figured out how to do what I needed to do.
First, note down the command args that will work with no issues with ffmpeg:

> -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://UN:PW@IP:554/live -err_detect ignore_err -r 10 -f image2pipe -

Next, you have so setup your process this way:

```
using (var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                Arguments = arguments,
                FileName = fFMpegExePath
            },
            EnableRaisingEvents = true
        })
        {
            // code body
        }
```

Now you need to **process.Start()** and then start listening to the **process.StandardOutput.BaseStream as FileStream** and handle the reading byte after byte.
Note that I set a low frame rate **-r 10** because if not set at all, the stream will hang for no visible reason but in this case I tested the task for more than 2 hours and it never fail.

I hope it helps you all who faced this issue.